# How to assert a CSV file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, minitest, testunit

Is there a nice way to assert the contents of a CSV file in Ruby?

I understand how to use the CSV libraries and how to read in the CSV file, but that results in a long list of assertions such as:

```
`assert_equal("0", @csv_array[0].field('impressions'))
 assert_equal("7", @csv_array[0].field('clicks'))
 assert_equal("330", @csv_array[0].field('currency.GBP.commissions'))
 assert_equal("6", @csv_array[0].field('currency.GBP.conversions'))
 assert_equal("3300", @csv_array[0].field('currency.GBP.ordervalue'))`
```

Is there some sort of file comparator so I could write:

```
assert_equal(expected.csv ,actual.csv )
```

or something along those lines?

Comment: Why not run a MD5 check on both and compare those values? See `man md5` if you're on a *nix or Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
expected_csv = "impressions,clicks,currency.GBP.comiisions,currency.GBP.conversions,currency.GBP.ordervalue
0,7,330,6,3300"
actual_csv = File.open('actual.csv').read
assert_equal(expected_csv, actual_csv)
```

That should work if the entire contents of the CSV file is only 2 lines. Otherwise you will have to manipulate `actual_csv` to get the parts you want to test. You could do that like so:

```
IO.readlines('actual.csv')[3]
```

That will get you the third line. You can then concatenate with a header line or compare to a string without the header.

Comment: thanks, it has many rows so went for your second solution which works

Answer (score 0):

If you have to test very output, you might find [approval testing](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) an interesting approach. Basically, the output is saved the first time your test runs. You can then check the output manually and approve it if correct. On subsequent runs, there will be an error when the output differs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick and dirty method for doing this which I may clean up and turn into a gem at some point.  https://gist.github.com/bpardee/513b4a15e5ebdc596e0b

For instance, the following code:

```
file = 'test.csv'
File.open(file, 'w') do |fout|
  fout.puts "foo,bar,zulu\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"
end
assert_csv(file) do |csv|
  csv << %w(foo bar warrior)
  csv << [1,3,5]
  csv << [4,5,6]
end
```

Would result in:

```
Missing columns: ["zulu"]
Unexpected columns: ["warrior"]
The following mismatches were found in line 2:
  bar actual=3 expected=2
```

I don't recommend this for big csv files since everything is loaded into memory.